# How to (re-)generate ActiveX Wrapper Classes with Visual Studio 10

Tags: visual-studio-2010, activex

... especially in the case of Non-Dialog Containers?

Hi folks,

I want to use ActiveX controls that are created in a view, not in a Dialog container, as described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/191es2w5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx . But in that article, the existence of the wrapper class is already supposed / not mentioned how to generate it. In the project that was handed me over, i found such generated classes.

For Dialog-Containers, the generator runs when I add a control varaible for the embedded activeX control, (again: not mentioned in msdn doc http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w98bewhf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx ). Workaorunds are possible (eg. creating a useless dialog just for that purpose), but there must be a "clean" way in Visual Studio!? I am a little bit disappointed by the MS-Documentation I found. If somebody could give me a hint, you could make me happy...